# What's the difference between "доверие", "доверительность", and "доверчивость"?

Tags: грамматика, разница

What's the difference between "доверие", "доверительность", and "доверчивость", grammatically speaking?

Comment: Are you sure you want to know about their grammatical differences (the different suffixes and declensions) and not their meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they're all nouns. These words are called **паронимы** There are special dictionaries on this topic. I will just give you a page from one of them. The differences between them don't translate well into English, but perhaps some examples will help.

Паронимы:
дове́рие — довери́тельность — дове́рчивость

Слова составляют паронимическую тройку.

**доверие**

— уверенность в чьей-нибудь добросовестности, искренности, в правильности чего-либо.

Примеры словосочетаний:
внушать доверие;
полное доверие;
доверие к человеку;
заслужить доверие.

Примеры предложений:
Этот человек больше не заслуживает моего доверия.
До серьезных отношений нужно проверить взаимопонимание и доверие друг другу.

**доверительность**

— выражение доверия.

Примеры словосочетаний:
доверительность отношений;
основы доверительности;
доверительность тона;
добродушная доверительность.

Примеры предложений:
Ничто не должно нарушать атмосферу доверительности.
Этот важный разговор придавал оттенок доверительности отношений всем участникам встречи.

**доверчивость**

— способность с легкостью доверяться кому-либо.

Примеры словосочетаний:
пользоваться доверчивостью;
детская доверчивость;
наивная доверчивость;
отличался доверчивостью.

Примеры предложений:
Девушка с романтической доверчивостью отдалась новому чувству.
Только хитрецы пользуются чужой доверчивостью.

https://paronymonline.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the exact grammatical difference?

Доверие is a neuter noun.

Доверчивость and доверительность are feminine nouns.